# Disable IE11 browser shortcut keys in Angular application

Tags: angular, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-11, keydown

I am trying to disable shortcuts keys for an Angular application.

I am using the following code in an Angular component:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
 handleHotkey(event: KeyboardEvent){
  ...
  //Do Something 
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This works properly in Google Chrome, but it is not working in Internet Explorer 11.

When I press ctrl+p then in IE11, print window opens along with the functionality which I defined in the function.

What would be the correct way to do this in IE11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

It seems like there is no solution for IE. There are 2 (ugly) alternatives: you can disable the `Ctrl` key entirely, or you can show an alert, and the print window won't show up. :(

**Not working:**

<s>Maybe `return false;` at the end of your method can solve this, I think.</s>

But it will cancel every `keydown` for the browser, so you should write and `if` statement to check `event.keyCode` or something like that, to decide if you should return `false` or `true` (to let the browser handle the other events).

Comment: @HarshRawat Can you confirm, that the code reaches that point? If yes, then you can also try `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` and `event.cancelBubble = true;`; if no, there is a possibility that IE doesn't allow to 'override' ctrl+P for some reason.

Comment: Yes the code reaches that point but it does not work. I think I understand what might be the problem. Are you aware about which event calls the shortcuts i.e. if it is keydown or other event ?

Comment: @HarshRawat I did a little research, but it seems like there is no solution for IE. Sorry. There are 2 (bad) alternatives: you can disable the Ctrl key entirely, or you can show an alert, and the print window won't show up. :(

Comment: Thanks for the update. I also think that it won't be possible. I moved to using alt for shortcuts.